# Error:Android Source Generator: IndexOutOfBoundsException after PC crash

Tags: android, android-studio

My PC has crashed occasionally, and after restart I got this, and can't run my project. What do to, who knows?

**UPDATED** for moderator: this is definitely Android Studio bug, so appropriate tag is important for whose who will search the same. The cause is in Android Studio's .idea file, I assume for now.

> Error:Android Source Generator: Error:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException   at
>   java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.read(ByteArrayInputStream.java:180)  at
>   com.intellij.util.io.CompressedAppendableFile$SegmentedChunkInputStream.read(CompressedAppendableFile.java:541)
>     at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)  at
>   com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMapValueStorage.readBytes(PersistentHashMapValueStorage.java:401)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.doGet(PersistentHashMap.java:518)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.get(PersistentHashMap.java:472)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.getState(AbstractStateStorage.java:117)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.runAaptCompiler(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:913)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.doBuild(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:210)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.build(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:114)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1237)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:911)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:983)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:870)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:696)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:387)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:194)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:294)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:232)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:44)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: delete **.idea** folder

Or better move it first to somewhere, on the case you forget something from configuration.

Android Studio 2.3.3